# Understanding the definition of Extreme subset of a convex set.

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

[image]

I am facing difficulty in understanding the definition of "Extreme subset of a convex set". By definition it should be convex but in example$1$ the Extreme subset is {$0,1$} which is not convex. One more point,
It looks from the definition that it shouldn't be unique. Am I correct?

Can anyone please explain this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Extreme subset of a convex set need not be unique.
Here. In example$1$ for $[0,1]$ extreme subset can be {$0$}, {$1$}, {$0,1$} or itself. If you define it to be convex then {$0,1$} can't extreme subset.

Answer (score 1):

The example is not saying that $\{0, 1\}$ is an extreme subset; rather it is saying that $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are two different extreme subsets.

Comment: What will be extreme subset here?

Comment: $\{0\}$ is an extreme subset of $[0,1]$. Another extreme subset is $\{1\}$. @Dirichletfan

Comment: Is it necessary that an extreme subset should be convex?

Comment: @Dirichletfan In the definition you provided, convexity seems to be required, but it seems that [in other contexts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119357/definition-of-an-extreme-set) it is not required.